# beforeInsert not triggered in grails + mongodb

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

it looks like beforeInsert is never triggered and the password is stored as plain text in DB, I have a User domain-class like this:

```
class User {

    String email
    String name
    String surname
    String phone
    String password

    static constraints = {
        email(blank:false, email:true, unique:true)
        name(blank:false)
        surname(blank:false)
        phone(blank:false)
        password(blank:false, password:true)
    }

    def beforeInsert = { encodePassword() }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
}
```

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's weird and I don't know why, but this works, I changed the beforeInsert var to a method, and added the transient springSecurityService

```
class User {

    transient springSecurityService

    String email
    String name
    String surname
    String phone
    String password

    static constraints = {
        email(blank:false, email:true, unique:true)
        name(blank:false)
        surname(blank:false)
        phone(blank:false)
        password(blank:false, password:true)
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you missed declaration of springSecurityService in the User class definition  (as @gurbieta observed):

```
transient springSecurityService
```

BTW, `beforeUpdate` method need some revision too. The mongodb gorm plugin does not support `dirty` checking methods.  See `1.1 Compatibility with GORM for Hibernate` in [doc](http://springsource.github.com/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/1.%20Introduction.html).

So you have to modify

```
if (isDirty('password')) {
```

to some other method to check if the password is changed.